# Django Queryset annotate based on unique value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to write a queryset operation that transforms the first table into the second table as efficiently as possible
This is the criteria:
For each name, how many unique schools are affiliated with it? Also, the exact names and schools are unknown beforehand.

| Name | School |
| --- | --- |
| John | USC |
| John | USC |
| John | UCLA |
| Adam | UCSD |
| Adam | USC |

| Name | num_unique_schools |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Adam | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Using **Values** method:

The students will be grouped by name, so you will only get an annotated result for each unique student name.

2- Using **Count** Method with *distinct* argument:

This is counting a "school" based a grouped student name , also remove duplicated schools.

code:

```
from django.db import models
    
results = StudentSchool.objects.values('name').annotate(
    num_unique_schools = models.Count('school', distinct=True)
).order_by("name")
```

**Test Case**

[image]